# Custom notification with Google Cast SDK v3

Tags: android, google-cast

Ever since the new *Google Cast SDK v3* has been out, I've been thinking about migrating to it, as it has a few features I need and I'm always interested in keeping everything as up-to-date as possible. My previous setup used *Google Cast SDK v2 + Cast Companion Library*. However I've been unable to find a way to provide a completely custom notification in the new *Google Cast SDK v3* which prevents me from using it.

With *Google Cast SDK v2 + Cast Companion Library* I was able to simply subclass the `VideoCastNotificationService` and override its `build` method to make a custom notification:

```
public class MyCastNotificationService extends VideoCastNotificationService {
    @Override
    protected void build(MediaInfo info, Bitmap bitmap, boolean isPlaying) {
        // ... build the custom notification
        mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)/*...*/.build();
    }
}
```

Then I could register the `MyCastNotificationService` in my `CastConfiguration` like this:

```
CastConfiguration castConfig = new CastConfiguration.Builder(APPLICATION_ID)
    /*...*/
    .setCustomNotificationService(MyCastNotificationService.class)
    .build();
```

However, with *Google Cast SDK v3* I've been unable to find a replacement that works. Here are the results of the bit of research I've done on this topic:

- The [`MediaNotificationService`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/MediaNotificationService) seems to be the component replacing the `VideoCastNotificationService`, however it does not seem to have a `build` method or anything similiar.
- Both the [`NotificationOptions.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/NotificationOptions.Builder) and [`CastMediaOptions.Builder`](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/CastMediaOptions.Builder) classes don't seem to have any methods for registering a custom notification service.
- The only documented way of customizing the notification seems to be custom action buttons as shown in the [Add Media Controls to Notification and Lock Screen](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#add_media_controls_to_notification_and_lock_screen) section, however I need to create a notification using the `RemoteViews` API, so this is not sufficient for me.

Has anyone been able to provide a custom notification using the new *Google Cast SDK v3*? As far as I can tell, this seems unsupported, but I'd love to be proven wrong here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I check the Google Cast documentation and I can't find any idea about your problem aside from the Notification service that you link. Maybe you are correct that this one is not yet supported but maybe someone expert here in the Google Cast have some idea on how to make this things possible.

Comment: I was unable to find any information on customizing the notification in v3 either.

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this?

Comment: There currently is no solution for this, but it is acknowledged and the Google Cast team is looking into it. See [Google Cast Issue #959](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=959).